# Ui breaks while using jQuery date picker

Tags: jquery, html

I am having an application which has a functionality of adding rows to an existing table. Please see the image below:

[image: table with added rows]

Here event date column is a date picker having a class called dp1. So each time add row button is clicked table rows are added. with a date picker and date picker works perfectly. When we need to change the previous buy date  after adding a new row ui breaks please see the error page image here:

[image: error page]

I am using jquery Date picker. Please see the code below:

```
<table class="table" id="even-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="select_all" id="checkall"
                                   type="checkbox"
                                   name="optionsCheckboxes">
                </label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Event Description</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <th></th>
        <th>Buy Date</th>
        <th>Sell Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><div class="checkbox">
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" class="check-class checkbox"
                                   name="optionsCheckboxes">
                        </label>
                    </div></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" class="form_control event_desc"></td>
        <td><input  type="text" name=""  class="form_control dp1"></td>
        <td><i  class="fa fa-calendar ca_icn"></i></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" disabled class="form_control">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="" disabled class="form_control">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Table row append code is given below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#checkall").click(function () {
        $(".checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    var markup = '<tr><td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" class="check-class checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"><span class="check"></span></span>'
    +'</label></div></td><td><input type="text" name="" class="form_control event_desc"></td><td><input  type="text"  name="" class="form_control dp1"></td><td><i class="fa fa-calendar ca_icn"></i></td> <td><input type="text" name="" disabled class="form_control">'
                                                +'</td> <td><input type="text" name="" disabled class="form_control"></td></tr>';
    $("table tbody").append(markup);
     });
// Find and remove selected table rows
    $("#removeRow").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="optionsCheckboxes"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Here is my date picker code

```
$('body').on('focus',".dp1", function(){
  $(this).datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
  })
});
```

Comment: `Please help me it is urgent.` there are currently 508.317 waiting before you. Please give us a moment. ;)

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Have you loaded **CSS AND JS** of datepicker?

Comment: yes i have loaded CSS AND JS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the class name of the table to append the Rows you created dynamically. Please find the fix below.

```
<table class="table event_table" id="even-table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="text-center">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input name="select_all" id="checkall"
                           type="checkbox"
                           name="optionsCheckboxes">
                </label>
            </div>
        </th>
        <th>Event Description</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <th>Buy Date</th>
        <th>Sell Date</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox"
                           class="check-class checkbox"
                           name="optionsCheckboxes">
                </label>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" name=""
                   placeholder="Iphone 10 introduction"
                   class="form_control event_desc"></td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">
                <input type="text" name=""
                       placeholder="March 5, 2018"
                       class="form_control dp1 date_field">
                <span class="fa fa-calendar ca_icn form-control-feedback"></span>
            </div>
        </td>

        <td><input placeholder="March 1, 2018" type="text" name="" disabled
                   class="form_control date_field ">
        </td>
        <td><input type="text" placeholder="March 10, 2018" name="" disabled
                   class="form_control date_field">
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

please notice the new class name "event_table"
Now append the newly created rows to this class name. please find the code below

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#checkall").click(function () {
    $(".checkbox").attr('checked', this.checked);
});
        $("#addRow").click(function(){

    var markup = '<tr><td><div class="checkbox"><label><input type="checkbox" name="optionsCheckboxes" class="check-class checkbox"><span class="checkbox-material"><span class="check"></span></span>'
    +'</label></div></td><td><input type="text" name="" placeholder="Iphone 10 introduction" class="form_control event_desc"></td><td><div class="form-group has-success has-feedback">'
                                                                +'<input type="text" name="" placeholder="March 5, 2018" class="form_control dp1 date_field ">'
                                                                +'<span class="fa fa-calendar ca_icn form-control-feedback"></span></div>'
                                                        +'</td><td><input type="text" name="" placeholder="March 1, 2018" disabled class="form_control date_field ">'
                                                +'</td> <td><input type="text" name="" disabled placeholder="March 10, 2018" class="form_control date_field"></td></tr>';
    $(".event_table tbody").append(markup);
    });

// Find and remove selected table rows
$("#removeRow").click(function(){
    $("table tbody").find('input[name="optionsCheckboxes"]').each(function(){
        if($(this).is(":checked")){
            $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        }
    });
});
```

});

find the datepicker code below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('body').on('focus',".dp1", function(){
    $(this).datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    })
});
```

});

Problem was your newly created table rows are clashed with the table of datepicker.

Comment: Thank you so much. It was the real problem. And now it is working perfectly.